How to determine the amount of electric current in the resistor R3


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
[![I want to find the magnitude of the current flowing through the resistor R3. I have difficulty analyzing the image. Do I also need to use the nodule or mesh method in calculating it?.]
1]1

Redraw the circuit and apply current division .You will get I as  3A

Redrawing isn't some pointless exercise; it's vital. Look at what I've done with R4: -

That should make things easier to understand. Now, you have two clear paths that the current \$I1\$ will flow down.

One path through R2 and,
One path through R1 + R3||R4

If you can calculate the parallel impedance of R3 and R4 and add it to R1 then the circuit reduces to just two resistors. Then it should be easy to find the current passing through R1 and, of course, that current is equally shared between R3 and R4.

I found the answer 1.04

@TenggaArlan that is incorrect for the current through R3

@TenggaArlan if we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

how much should it be

@TenggaArlan if you follow my answer you are left with 2 branches that carry current. One branch clearly has a resistance of 6 ohm and, the other branch is 2 ohm in series with two parallel 4 ohm resistors. Can you calculate what resistance that branch has? Once you have that 2nd branch resistance, the 10 amps splits into values that are inversely proportional to the branch resistances.

hmmmmmm i try wait

There are many ways to approach problems like this. And I fully understand how difficult it can be, when starting out, to figure out any one approach let alone all of them. You have some tools (I don't know what they are) to apply, hopefully. But all I can do is guess about what is better for you in this case. It's a matter of what you have in your head. And I can't tell what's there and what's missing.
So, for now, I can suggest at least this one idea.
Let's first start out by selecting one of the nodes (wires) and calling it "ground" for now:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
You can now see that \$R_2\$ is in parallel to \$R_1+\left(R_3\vert\vert R_4\right)\$. Just by inspection, you can see that this means the left branch is \$4\:\Omega\$ and the right branch is \$6\:\Omega\$. This means that \$V_x=24\:\text{V}\$. (Think this out and confirm that you see what I see here.)
From that fact you can work out the portion of \$10\:\text{A}\$ that must be going though \$R_2\$ as \$4\:\text{A}\$. So the rest, \$6\:\text{A}\$, must be going through \$R_1\$. Not so?
You can work out the voltage drop across \$R_1\$, knowing that detail, as \$12\:\text{V}\$.
This means that the remainder, another \$V_y= 12\:\text{V}\$, must be across the remaining pair of parallel resistors.
It should be very easy to now see what the current \$I\$ is.
There are other methods. Many, in fact. But this is one approach to the problem.

where do you put V_0

@TenggaArlan I picked (and you can pick something different) the bottom wire in your schematic as $0:\text{V}$. Seemed the easier thing to do.

For a simple circuit like this it may help to reorganise it into a more conventional diagram. Redraw it with the power supply positive on top and negative on the bottom.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Figure 1.
Now move and connect up R3 and R4.
Update your question and add in your attempt at redrawing the circuit and we'll take it from there.
Tip: There's a CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. You can use that to create your circuit. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' to rotate, 'H' to flip horizontal, 'V' to flip vertical. When you use the Save and Insert button an editable version is saved in your post. You don't need a CircuitLab account and don't need to upload images.

Follow up:
You've already accepted an answer but this is how I would draw it following the "current flows from top to bottom" convention.

simulate this circuit
Figure 2.
Now it should be easy to merge parallel and series branches one at a time.

I have edited it can you review it again
